# Auto increment column after inserting same value

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to auto increment column after inserting the same value and also check the duplicate value of maximum of 2 like this:

```
INSERT INTO info (name, date, sched) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$sched')
// I want to auto increment for count column after inserting same date and sched
INSERT INTO appointment (date, sched) VALUES ('$date', '$sched')
```

Here is my table:

[image: table 1 for info and appoint for table 2]

Somebody can help me to achieve that or suggest a better way for appointment scheduling? Thanks!

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Why would you have a `count` column instead of just doing `COUNT()` in a query?

Comment: because i just want to limit per appointment

Comment: I don't see how that necessitates maintaining the count in a column. Just select the count of matching rows before inserting. If you've reached the max, don't allow the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, table design like this:

```
create table appointment (
    id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    date date not null '2018-01-01',
    sched varchar(20) not null defalut '',
    count int(11) not null default 0,
    primary key (id)
    unique key `date_sched` (`date`, `sched`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then, sql like this:

```
insert into appointment(date, sched, count) values ($date, $sched, $count) 
on duplicate key update count = count + 1
```